# Can't get my W7/Ubuntu dual boot to reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I generally don't like to result to asking for help, but guys, I am completely lost. I had a dual boot system working great until I ran

```
apt-get do-release-upgrade
```

It progressed fine, I restarted and instead of GRUB, I was greeted with a black screen and a blinking underscore. I popped in a live USB to do a boot-repair but I can't get the thing to boot to it. I have tried playing with secure boot in BIOS, setting boot priorities, clearing CMOS *then* setting boot priorities all to no avail. I get the Windows prompt "loading operating system..." with an underscore with all of them.

My last ditch effort was removing EVERYTHING. HDDs, ethernet cable, DVD drive, and only booting with my display, computer, and Live USB. I still got the Windows "loading operating system..." prompt. My head is spinning, I can't figure out what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is sytem UEFI? What brand model system? Did you remove all ppa's & proprietary drivers before upgrading?

Comment: No, it is not UEFI. It is a Gigabyte 990FX-UD3 mobo. I didn't remove anything before upgrading.

Comment: Back up a bit: You wrote "I have tried playing with secure boot in BIOS." Secure Boot is a feature *only* on UEFIs, not on BIOSes. If you see any Secure Boot options in your firmware setup screen, then your firmware is UEFI-based. (The manufacturer may call it a "BIOS," but that's a lie.) If you've got a UEFI, then my guess is that there's crud in the NVRAM that's causing it to malfunction. Using an option to reset everything to the defaults might help, but you might then need to re-install your boot loader. My [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB drive might help.

Comment: In any event, please go back and check the firmware type. Also, if you can put the hard disk in another computer and check its partition table type, that might be helpful, too. It would be either GPT or MBR (which `parted` reports as `msdos`).

Comment: I actually misspoke. It wasn't "secure boot" it was enabling and disabling EFI. I have been reading so many guides my words got mixed up.

Comment: Gigabyte's all need IOMMU settings and boot parameter: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292025 and:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242023 Somewhat diferent parameters: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254677

Comment: How can I edit those parameters if I can't boot into the OS, or even a live disk for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair your MBR, when messing with Grub, or not properly installing it, or trying to use a beta version you will encounter the black screen as there is no boot loader to choose from. Do the following with a Windows repair disc or bootable USB:

> > When you insert the Windows installation media choose "Repair my computer>Troubleshoot>Advanced>Command prompt". Run the following command:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

This will fix the Windows boot loader so Windows boots right up after restarting.

I would suggest starting over with Ubuntu if you can to properly install it. Get booted up into the installer, remove the old partitions (not the Windows ones), and then re-creating them again. This would ensure a fresh install of Ubuntu

NOTE** Running the fixmbr option will fix the normal windows bootloader. You will no longer have the option to get into linux, or see the grub menu. This is the fix I know of.